# Loop function through dataframe, differentiate, and then combine per column in original dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm trying to use the package ballr to collect some datafrom basketballreference. I'm trying to use the NBASeasonTeamByYear function to collect the season results of teams across multiple seasons. That is I want every team's data for the years 2017 to 2020, before combining the dataframes into 2 larger ones seperated by conference.

I first made a dataframe with each team's code and conference

```
league_teams <- data.frame("team" = c("ATL", "BOS", "NJN", "CHA", "CHI", "CLE", "DAL", "DEN", 
                                  "DET", "GSW", "HOU", "IND", "LAC", "LAL", "MEM", "MIA",
                                  "MIL", "MIN", "NOH", "NYK", "OKC", "ORL", "PHI", "PHO",
                                  "POR", "SAC", "SAS", "TOR", "UTA", "WAS"), 
                       "conference" = c("East", "East", "East", "East", "East", "East", "West",
                                        "West", "East", "West", "West", "East", "West", "West",
                                        "West", "East", "East", "West", "West", "East", "West",
                                        "East", "East", "West", "West", "West", "West", "East",
                                        "West", "East"))
league_teams$team <- as.character(league_teams$team)
league_teams$conference <- as.factor(league_teams$conference)
```

Now I'm having trouble writing the loop that first uses the function for each unique team using their code and the years I want before combining them irregardless of year but within each conference.

I started with this

```
   for (team in league_teams) {

  team_2017 <- NBASeasonTeamByYear(team = team, 2017)
  team_2017$season <- as.factor(2017)
  team_2017$team <- as.factor(team)

}
```

The latter lines illustrating that I want to add 2 columns one for the respective year and one for the respective team code, but not only for 2017 but all the way through 2020. Though I'm having trouble writing the loop and think I use rbind to combine them later on but I'm unsure how to do so and discriminate by conference in the original dataframe I made.

Answer (score 1):

Consider generalizing your process in a user-defined method and pass params with `expand.grid` (all combinations) and `Map` (elementwise loop):

```
nba_df_build <- function(yr, team, conf) {    
  # base::TRANSFORM OR dplyr::MUTATE
  transform(NBASeasonTeamByYear(team = team, season = yr),         
            season = as.factor(yr),
            team = as.factor(team),
            conference = as.factor(conf))  
}

params_df <- expand.grid(year = 2017:2020,
                         team = league_teams$team,
                         conference = league_teams$conference)

df_list <- Map(nba_df_build, params_df$year, params_df$team, params_df$conference)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
#final_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)
```

And for any splitting of data frames:

```
# LIST OF TWO CONFERENCE DATA FRAMES
conference_dfs <- split(final_df, final_df$conference)

# LIST OF FOUR SEASON DATA FRAMES
season_dfs <- split(final_df, final_df$season)

# LIST OF THIRTY TEAM DATA FRAMES
team_dfs <- split(final_df, final_df$team)
```